# How to make bootstrap-datetimepicker work with knockout on Firefox

Tags: javascript, datetime, knockout.js, datetimepicker

I have a date time variable "whenDateTime" that is read from my db on the format (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000).
I want to set a datetimepicker with this date time, then be able to manipulate it, and of course write it back to my db.

For some reason the datetimepicker will not trigger. Where do I go wrong?

This is my view model:

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.whenDateTime = ko.observable("2016-04-09T19:24:48.000");

  self.viewWhenDateTime = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var mydate = self.whenDateTime();
            if (!mydate) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return moment(mydate).format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm");
            }
        },
        write: function (newVal) {
            var reversed = moment(newVal).format();
            self.whenDateTime(reversed);
        }
    });
}
```

The bindingHandlers is like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dateTimePicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().dateTimePickerOptions || {};
        $(element).datetimepicker(options);

        //when a user changes the date, update the view model
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "dp.change", function (event) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                if (event.date != null && !(event.date instanceof Date)) {
                    value(event.date.toDate());
                } else {
                    value(event.date);
                }
            }
        });

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            var picker = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
            if (picker) {
                picker.destroy();
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var picker = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
        //when the view model is updated, update the widget
        if (picker) {
            var koDate = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

            //in case return from server datetime i am get in this form for example /Date(93989393)/ then fomat this
            koDate = (typeof (koDate) !== 'object') ? new Date(parseFloat(koDate.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))) : koDate;

            picker.date(koDate);
        }
    }
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/v54hnxur/

Comment: There are errors in your jsfiddle's console

Comment: I see those, but can´t see what is causing them.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/236/

Comment: Thanks @Matt.kaaj What did you do? It seems however that the datetimepicker screws up the date.

Comment: Yes .there is an issue with your `date reg Expression `. As you can see here it works here https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/237/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matt.kaaj! :)
I have only two remaining issues: 1)The input isn´t set with the starting date when the fiddle is run, and 2) when clicking the input the date is set to now()  PS: Paste it as an answer (not comment) and I can check it as solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/237/), it actually shows `09/04/2016 7:24 PM` for `2016-04-09T19:24:48.000` and when I change the input date it gets changed properly. I couldn't replicate what you mentioned.

Note whenever moment.js wants to parse a date if that date is undefined or provided in a wrong format, it displays the current date instead.

Comment: I get it working as well, but with Crome only. Neither Safari (on both Mac Windows) and Firefox initialize the input.

Comment: I guess the date parser on `FireFox` and `Safari` cannot recognize the `DD:MM:YYY` format. Firefox's behavior looks to be more strict than Chrome's. For example, change the format to `MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm` or `MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm` if `moment.js` supports and test it if it works on FF Safari . https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/240/

Comment: I also got it working with commenting out the line //koDate = (typeof (koDate) !== 'object') ? new Date(koDate) : '';